# What's the strategy to merge Long-term feature branch and master branch?

Tags: git, merge

A long-term feature branch may last for more than two weeks for example. During this time, a lot of other feature/bugfix branches may be merged onto master branch.

Sometime the long-term feature branch need those branches, such as branches fixed a blocking fatal bug.

So I try to merge master branch onto the long-term feature branch every two days. In the end, I merge feature branch onto master.

```
M1 -> M2 -> M3 -> M4 -> M5
 \    \     \     \  /
F1 -> F2 -> F3 -> F4
```

But in fact, I would like a history below:

```
M1 -> M2 -> M3 -> M4 -> M5
 \                   /
F1 -> F2 -> F3 -> F4
```

Because I can revert the whole branch when I revert M5.

I DO NOT like `merge --squash feature`, because there are more than one people involve the feature branch, I want the history remain.

```
M1 -> M2       -> M3        -> M4    -> M5
 \                                     /
F1 -> M2'-> F2 -> M3' -> F3 -> M4' -> F4
```

M' means the commit produced by 'merge --squash master', but it's not good I think.

So what's the best way to merge master and long-term feature branches?

Comment: Those are contradictory goals - if rewriting history (squashing/rebasing) is not an option, then you have to accept that the commit history will represent the actual sequence of merge operations that took place over time.  (The **real** solution is to avoid long-term branches with multiple contributors...)

Comment: Instead of merging I rebase on top of master. This way my commits are always on top. History is somewhat preserved (the commit order/contents, at least).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: maybe those multiple contributors could branch off the feature branch and send PRs :)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth a feature with front-end and back-end has two developers to work together.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it's too bad to rebase a long-term feature branch, every resolved conflicts shows at the next rebasing.

Comment: @企业应用架构模式大师: that it does...

Comment: You can already revert the whole branch by reverting M5.  There are some caveats.  See the `--mainline` option for [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) and the [revert-a-faulty-merge.txt document](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt).

Comment: @ SergioTulentsev: I made a mistake, resolved conflicts do not shows in the next rebase. But it must be push by `--force`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of merging master in your feature branch, you can rebase master in it ; with of course an updated master :

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

At the end of the feature, you merge it in master with `--no-ff` option (no fast-forward) to keep the bifurcation :

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff feature
```

And then you get something like that :

```
M1 - M2 - M3             M4 - M5 - M6
            \           /
             F1 - F2 - F3
```

The M4 commit will be a merge commit, which you can revert if you what to remove the feature.

Comment: Quote from OP: "there are more than one people involved - I want the history to remain"

Comment: The history will remain even if there is more people.
What i can add is to pull with rebase set to preserve : `git pull --rebase=preserve` which is, i think, a very good practice

Comment: Rebase definitely does not preserve the original history, by definition.

Comment: I didn't say to rebase feature in master but the opposite.
If you rebase master in feature (like my code example), master will be at the bottom of feature, and both history will be preserved, i guarantee

Comment: No - `rebase` creates new commits and deletes the old ones.  That's fine if you're the only one using that branch, but causes significant pain if others are contributing to it.

Comment: if you are the only one on the feature branch you can rebase master in it when you want.

if there is more people involved, you have to force push the branch, that's right (with a `--force-with-lease`), but every one will get the updated feature branch and the both history will be preserved.

i think that is what he is looking for

Comment: That prevents the push from wiping other people's work, but it doesn't protect other people from miserable merge experiences when they pull.

Comment: And we arrive to the pull with rebase, which avoid the merge and make a rebase (at the pull).
I do it every day. It should be the default behavior i think :)

Comment: the rebase problem is every resolved conflicts shows at the next rebasing.

Comment: For this you can look at `git rerere`, which replay your resolution for the same conflicts